# Catch when a grid space contains something

Tags: java, for-loop

So I am trying to use a for-loop in my Java program but I can't figure out how to return true if two values match. I am using a `List<int[]>` and a `int[]`. Here is my code:

```
public class ClickableObject 
{
    List<int[]> objectCoords;
    public ClickableObject(List<int[]> gridSpaces)
    {
        objectCoords = gridSpaces;
    }
    public boolean isClicked(int[] clickCoords)
    {
        // This loop is not working
        for(int i = 0; i < objectCoords.size(); i++)
        {
            if(clickCoords == objectCoords.get(i))
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method `isClicked(int[] clickCoords)` takes in a two-integer array, which has the x and y coordinates of the click. It should run it through and find if an `int[]` in `objectCoords` matches the clickCoords.

Comment: this is wrongly implemented... ***clickCoords==objectCoords.get(i)***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
Arrays.deepEquals(clickCoords, objectCoords.get(i))
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29